# how can i find the specfic class from the given form element by selecting the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I developing a quiz app and I want to select a specific class from the given below in the javascript file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h2> Css stand For</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check1">
        <label for="check1">Cascading stylesheet</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" class="error" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check2">
        <label for=" check2">Cascading stylesheet</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" class="error" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check3">
        <label for=" check3">Cascading
            stylesheet</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" class="error" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check4">
        <label for=" check4">Cascading
            stylesheet<label>
    </div>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the javascript function to select the given input check box but I can't get the property to select the specific class

```
let btn = document.getElementById('send');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let check = document.querySelectorAll('checkbox');
    // console.log(check);
    check.forEach(addEventListener('change', getItem));
    function getItem() {
        console.log(2);
    }

    
});
```

Comment: Which class do you want to access?

Comment: Array.prototype.forEach accepts a callback function as 1st parameter, you have to replace `addEventListener('change', getItem)` to `e => e.addEventListener('change', getItem)`. It does not resolve your issue but as @smtaha512 says, we need more info to help you

Comment: the class = "ansewer" b/c if i access and get this class I say this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where I listen form submit [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), then I check if the good answer is selected. I think it answers to your initial question. Of course with this implementation if all checkboxes are checked, it is considered as a good answer too.

However the best solution will vary depending on your needs.
There are a lot of way to create quizz.

For example, if I had to make a quizz I will prefer to use input name attribute instead of class and maybe write expected answers directly in a data-attribute to the form element. But it depends if I have multiple question on a same page and if the validator must be for the entire form or each questions ... etc.

So to go futher, I recommand you to learn what you can do with a [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) ($form), and maybe how to use [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) too. I hope it will give you tools you need to achieve your quizz.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Css stand For</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="quizz">
            <input type="checkbox" class="answer" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check1">
            <label for="check1">Cascading stylesheet</label><br>
    
            <input type="checkbox" class="error" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check2">
            <label for=" check2">Cascading stylesheet</label><br>
    
            <input type="checkbox" class="error" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check3">
            <label for=" check3">Cascading
                stylesheet</label><br>
    
            <input type="checkbox" class="error" value="Cascading stylesheet" id="check4">
            <label for=" check4">Cascading
                stylesheet<label>

            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        document.getElementById('quizz').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent sending HTML form and change page
            const $form = e.currentTarget;
            const $answer = $form.querySelector('.answer');
            alert($answer.checked ? 'Good' : 'Wrong');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```